# How to release memory in python wx.MemoryDC

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I can't use script twice in IDE, my guess it's because memory is not released. I tried to do something, but I don't really know how I should release it.

```
import wx
import win32gui
from ctypes import windll

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Steam')

# Window_FromHWND appears in wxPython 2.6.2.1+
def getScreenshot():
    window = wx.Window_FromHWND(None, hwnd)

    src_dc = wx.WindowDC(window)
    width, height = window.GetSize()

    mem_dc = wx.MemoryDC()
    bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(width, height)
    mem_dc.SelectObject(bitmap)

    windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, mem_dc.GetHDC() , 0)

    mem_dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

    mem_dc.Clear()
    src_dc.Clear()
    window.Destroy()
    mem_dc.Destroy()
    src_dc.Destroy()

    return bitmap.ConvertToImage()

app = wx.App(redirect=False)

image = getScreenshot()
filename = "testsnap.png"
image.SaveFile(filename, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
image.Destroy()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You really shouldn't need to do memory management in Python. I think all of your clear() and destroy() calls are superfluous (and possibly dangerous).

Comment: actually its probably because your file is open somewhere... what makes you think the problem is memory related?

Comment: You are starting the application main loop and never exit it!

Comment: @SteveBarnes I added app.ExitMainLoop() at the end, still gives me "The wx.App object must be created first!" at second call.

Comment: It's a __loop__ so your exit is never reached... since you are not actually creating and using any GUI components for user interaction try commenting out the `app.MainLoop`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `app.MainLoop()` at all, because your program should exit as soon as you've saved your image.